# Plotting response r(t) from R(s)

Tags: function, matlab, math, plot, system

For system function H(s)=s^2/(s^2+4) and the input E(s)=1/s^2. The response was calculated to be R(s)=1/(s^2+4). How can I plot this in time domain?

I tried using lsim which didn't really make sense to me. I also tried using step() but I thought this is used when the input in a step function

Comment: I don't remember the maths too well, but isn't the impulse response (`impulse()`) of R(s) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Using below MATLAB code will give you the response of system:

```
clear all; close all; clc; clf;

sys = tf([1 0 0],[1 0 4]);

t = 0:0.01:10;
u = t;
lsim(sys,u,t)   % u,t define the input signal
```

Your input is `E(s)=1/s^2` and its Laplace Inverse is equal to `t`. That's why in above code, we have `u = t`.

Below is the plot of response:

[image]

gray line is input which is `t`. The blue sinusoidal line is the response of system. It is compatible with your response. The response is `R(s)=1/(s^2+4)` and its Laplace Inverse is `0.5*sin(2*t)`, as you see in above plot as response.